# What differences are there between the XFL rules of today and the rules of XFL past?

Tags: rules, american-football

As the title states - I know XFL was a league in the past, with rule differences between them and the NFL. I see the list of XFL/NFL rule differences of the **current** XFL league exist [here](https://www.xfl.com/en-US/rules), but I'm wondering if these are the same rules as XFL past or not?

The main reason for asking is - I am curious as to whether or not the viewing experience will be the same as it was in the failed XFL league of the past, or if there are new innovations to the league that may ensure it's success this time around?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know all the rules of the XFL of the past, but they definitely tried to portray a more aggressive and violent form of the game. Instead of a coin toss, they had a [Scramble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvN4mOkZ3fo). One player from each team run to the ball placed in the middle of the field. The players were more than 20 yards from the ball. The player who gains possession of the ball first, their team gets to decide if they want to Receive the kick or Defer. This also applied to over-time. This resulted in a significant number of injuries to those players.